# App Crash On Google Play Games Services Login

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, google-play-services, google-play-games, crash-reports

I am attempting to test google play game services within my game but whenever I try to sign into the service my game "stops working", as in crashes. I am trying to troubleshoot this problem with the logcats sent to android device monitor, but it doesn't tell me what is going wrong with the google play game services. For instance, these are the logs once I tap the achievements button in my app (since I am not signed in yet it attempts to sign in before displaying achievements):

```
10-27 15:25:22.405: I/Unity(15089): UnityIAP Promo: Clearing promo product metadata
10-27 15:25:22.405: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:22.405: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:22.683: D/ViewRootImpl@ddd8e3d[UnityPlayerActivity](15089): ViewPostIme pointer 0
10-27 15:25:22.746: D/ViewRootImpl@ddd8e3d[UnityPlayerActivity](15089): ViewPostIme pointer 1
10-27 15:25:23.376: D/ViewRootImpl@ddd8e3d[UnityPlayerActivity](15089): ViewPostIme pointer 0
10-27 15:25:23.429: D/ViewRootImpl@ddd8e3d[UnityPlayerActivity](15089): ViewPostIme pointer 1
10-27 15:25:23.450: I/Unity(15089): Cannot show leaderboard: not authenticated
10-27 15:25:23.450: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.450: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.500: D/GamesUnitySDK(15089): Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
10-27 15:25:23.537: I/Unity(15089): Building GPG services, implicitly attempts silent auth
10-27 15:25:23.537: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.537: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.602: W/Unity(15089): !!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/27/18 15:25:23 -04:00 WARNING: Creating new PlayGamesPlatform
10-27 15:25:23.602: W/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.602: W/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/27/18 15:25:23 -04:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/27/18 15:25:23 -04:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/27/18 15:25:23 -04:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/27/18 15:25:23 -04:00 DEBUG: Creating Android IPlayGamesClient Client
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089):  
10-27 15:25:23.602: I/Unity(15089): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
```

To my surprise they even just updated the google play game services unity plugin 2 days ago so that it now works with newer gms libraries, but it still won't work for me. This leads me to believe it is probably a different issue. Any advice would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this issue please follow the steps:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2217#issuecomment-417619382
Worked perfectly for me and you don't need to downgrade any libraries!